# Why you should not use the CSS selector * in production code?

Tags: css, css-selectors

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Here is a direct quote:

> While this is certainly fine for quick tests, I'd advise you to never use this in production code. It adds too much weight on the browser, and is unnecessary.

I see this selector in many websites so obviously it is used in production code. What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure how it is unnecessary, but for sure it adds much weight on the browser.

Comment: Just plain FUD. There is nothing inherently bad about using * if you know what you're doing. Use it if you absolutely need to, and if profiling shows that it is indeed causing noticeable jank (which is vanishingly unlikely unless you're either dealing with performance critical code, or very large HTML pages), *then* find a replacement.